# useRef to control a component that is inside child component

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am developing react-native project.

I have created a custom component inside which I use a 3rd party library component. The 3rd party library component needs the `useRef` hook from my code so that I can control the library component.

```
    import React, {useRef} from 'react';
    ...
    const MyComponent = () => {
      const ref = useRef();
      return (
        <View>
          <Button
            title="OPEN 3rd party component"
            onPress={() => ref.current.open()}
          /> 
          <LibraryComponent
            ref={ref}
            ...
          />
        </View>)
}
```

Now, I have a screen named `MyScreen`, I need to show `MyComponent` on `MyScreen`, and control that library component from `MyScreen` instead of `MyComponent`. So, I refactored `MyComponent` to this (I removed the `Button` and change `ref` to be a pass-in property):

```
const MyComponent = ({ref}) => {
    
      return (
        <View>
          <LibraryComponent
            ref={ref}
            ...
          />
        </View>)
}
```

Then, in `MyScreen` :

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import MyComponent from '../components/MyComponent';

export const MyScreen = () => {
    const screenRef = useRef();
    ...

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button onPress=>{()=>screenRef.current.open()}/>
          <MyComponent ref={screenRef}>
          ...
      </View>
    )
   
}
```

But I get warning message: `Function components cannot be give refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.  Did you mean to use React.ForwardRef() ?`

My questions is:

How to get rid of that warning & having `MyScreen` control the library component with reference hook?

**======== UPDATE =======**

I changed the name of the property in `MyComponent` from `ref` to `innerRef` like @Rishabh Anand suggested. The warning disappeared.

```
const MyComponent = ({innerRef}) => {
  ...
}
```

MyScreen is now:

```
  export const MyScreen = () => {
        const screenRef = useRef();
        ...
    
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <Button onPress=>{()=>screenRef.current.open()}/>
              <MyComponent innerRef={screenRef}>
              ...
          </View>
        )
       
    }
```

But now a new issue comes, when I click on the `Button` of `MyScreen`, app crashed with error `undefined is not an object (evaluating screenRef.current.open)`. It seems the `screenRef.current` holds a `null` instead of the library component. Why?

Comment: `ref` is a keyword in React, basically every component will have one and can only be set not passed to a child. If you can try and change the name from `ref` in MyScreen to something like `innerRef` when you're passing the prop to `<MyComponent innerRef={screenRef} />`?

Comment: @Rishabh, Yep, thanks. But now a new issue comes, when I click on the `Button` of MyScreen, app crashed with error `undefined is not an object (evaluating screenRef.current.open)`. It seems the `screenRef.current` holds a null instead of the library component. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use React.forwardRef

From the docs: https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

```js
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Cliquez ici</FancyButton>;
```

You can after you set a ref, call some function inside your child component like this:

```js
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    click: () => {
      onClick();
    },
  }));

  const onClick = () => {
    console.log('Clicked.');
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} className="FancyButton">
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
});

const ref = React.createRef();
  <FancyButton ref={ref}>Cliquez ici</FancyButton>;
```

And call from your parent component

> ref.current.click()